# Getting "ERROR 2026 (HY000): SSL connection error: ASN: bad other signature confirmation" when try to connect to localhost mysql server

Tags: mysql, ssl

I followed the article 
http://www.madirish.net/214 ,
generated server certificates as

ssl-ca=server.csr

ssl-cert=server.cert

ssl-key=server.key

and client certificate as
ssl-ca=client.csr

ssl-cert=client.cert

When I try to connect mysql client I got the below result :

[root@sumit mysql-cert]# mysql -uroot -padmin --ssl-ca=/etc/ssl/mysql-cert/client.csr --ssl-cert=/etc/ssl/mysql-cert/client.cert --ssl-key=/etc/ssl/mysql-cert/server.key

Warning: Using a password on the command line interface can be insecure.

ERROR 2026 (HY000): SSL connection error: ASN: bad other signature confirmation

I tried same command from remote machine and got the below error

ERROR 2026 (HY000): SSL connection error
Help me to get out of this .

Comment: .csr is an extension I normally associate with a certificate signing request. That's not an extension I would expect to see on a CA certificate. Is it possible you're using the wrong file for your --ssl-ca?

Answer (score 2):

As Charley noted, I think that .csr file is just wrong—I ran into the same issue trying to follow that same article (and met with the same error).  I followed this article (https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/creating-ssl-certs.html) for generating the keys and certs, and that worked.  The gist:

```
# Create CA certificate
shell> openssl genrsa 2048 > ca-key.pem
shell> openssl req -new -x509 -nodes -days 3600 \
     -key ca-key.pem -out ca-cert.pem

# Create server certificate, remove passphrase, and sign it
# server-cert.pem = public key, server-key.pem = private key
shell> openssl req -newkey rsa:2048 -days 3600 \
     -nodes -keyout server-key.pem -out server-req.pem
shell> openssl rsa -in server-key.pem -out server-key.pem
shell> openssl x509 -req -in server-req.pem -days 3600 \
     -CA ca-cert.pem -CAkey ca-key.pem -set_serial 01 -out server-cert.pem

# Create client certificate, remove passphrase, and sign it
# client-cert.pem = public key, client-key.pem = private key
shell> openssl req -newkey rsa:2048 -days 3600 \
     -nodes -keyout client-key.pem -out client-req.pem
shell> openssl rsa -in client-key.pem -out client-key.pem
shell> openssl x509 -req -in client-req.pem -days 3600 \
     -CA ca-cert.pem -CAkey ca-key.pem -set_serial 01 -out client-cert.pem
```

Then ca-cert.pem is ssl-ca on both sides, the server gets server-[key/cert].pem for ssl-cert and ssl-key, and the client gets the client ones.

Answer (score 1):

I encountered the same bad signature error for a set of certs and client / sever environments which previously worked fine.  I assumed that something must have changed in one the environments that I wasn't accounting for, since the files and methods of using them were all identical.  After wasting a lot of time, I discovered the CA had simply expired!  I must have accidentally messed up the expiration settings when generating the certs.  In an ideal world, this error message would say something more meaningful, but since it does not - here's an important couple of (obvious) steps to take if you encounter this nebulous error:

Try validating your certs against the CA:

```
sudo openssl verify -CAfile [CA PATH] [CERT PATH]
```

Try viewing the CA as text:

```
sudo openssl x509 -in [CA PATH] -text -noout
```